# Extract Samsung OEM recovery from laptop HDD

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios, uefi

I have a Samsung NP540U3C with Windows 8. I recovered it to factory condition, booted and it was fine.

There were 107 Windows updates so I downloaded and installed them, rebooted and then I was greeted to a blue screen boot loop. The error was ACPI BIOS error.

Googling this told me to reset the BIOS but I can't get into it. I unplugged the CMOS battery, left for 30 minutes but it that didn't work either.

I took out the HDD and it boots from a flash drive okay. I put the HDD into a dock and it has 6 partitions, two of them have recovery media. Is it possible to extract these to a USB drive, wipe the HDD and use it to reinstall Windows on the HDD whilst on the laptop?

Any ideas?